# About laravel eloquent - how to get specified column value in database

Tags: ajax, database, laravel-5.1

i'm new to Laravel, i'm using laravel 5.1
I want to get the specified column in the database.

It's my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $markQuizs = MarkAss::select('year')->where('user_id','=','abc001')->get();
    return view('marks-management', ['markQuizs'=> $markQuizs]);
}
```

In the view page, i try to echo

> $markQuizs

but it got

> [{"year":2016}]

how can i only get the "2016" value? Does it need ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $markQuizs = MarkAss::select('year')->where('user_id','=','abc001')->first();
    return view('marks-management', ['markQuizs'=> $markQuizs->year]);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the help but now it got {"year":2016} without the "[    ]"~ can i just only get the "2016" ??

Comment: can you please check answer carefully? In the return statement I used $markQuizs->year instead of $markQuizs. Or you can use $markQuizs->year in your view too.